# get value from hidden field on click of each jquery/ajax retrieved image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

am displaying images using jquery and php with a hidden field input that contains the file name. i want when each image is clicked i get value of the hidden field into a text box.

here is my sample code
jquery for retreiving

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {               

      $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",
        url: "getimages.php",             
        dataType: "html",                   
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#refresh").append(response); 
            
        }

    });
});
```

php code for retrieving the images

```html
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM files");
 while($val = $re->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
 $name = $val['file_name'];
  
  echo '<div class="image">
  <input type="hidden" name="link" id="getname" value="'.$name.'" />
  <img id="img" src="http://localhost/web/images/'.$val['file_name'].'" /></a>
  
  </div>';
 };
```

code for getting hidden field value to textbox on click of each image

```js
   
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#img").each(function(index){
   $(this).click(function(){
   
 var post=$(this).parent().parent().find('#getname').val();
 
 var tbox = document.getElementById('txtbox'); 
 tbox.value = post; 
 });
 
 });
 });
```

and the textbox

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbox" />
```

the problem is when i click on each image the textbox does not get populated.

what am i suppose to do.

Note** the images and hidden input where retrieved using jquery as shown in my question

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In you php code, you are returning id's in a `while` loop which duplicates you id's when the while loop gives more than 1 result.

You are getting your images with an `$.ajax` call, so you should move the attaching of the clickhandler into the `success` callback. You can do this for example:

You can remove the id's from the html that is being returned:

```
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM files");
while($val = $re->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $name = $val['file_name'];

    echo '<div class="image">
        <input type="hidden" name="link" value="'.$name.'" />
        <img width="100" src="images/'.$name.'" /></a>

        </div>';
};
```

You can update the way you find the images to `$(".image img")` and find the hidden `input` field using `.prev`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tbox = document.getElementById('txtbox');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getimages.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#refresh").append(response);
            $(".image img").each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    tbox.value = $(this).prev('input').val();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks The Fourth bird this was a perfect answer. i only replaced $(this).prev('input').val();  with $(this).parent().parent().find(':hidden').val(); to display the value to textbox

Comment: @user3269519 You are welcome. You can always consider marking this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.